# how to submit a form in javascript when a user presses the enter keyboard

Tags: javascript, html

what code or what can i add to my html. or js. file to make it submit the form when someone presses the enter keyboard? **this my html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test Form</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


 <h3>Start Here</h3>
   UserName: <input type="text" id="user"><br>

    Master Code: <input type = "password" id = "pass"><br><br>


   <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick= "check()">
</body>
</html>
```

**and this is my external javascript file**

```
function check()
{
var t = document.getElementById("user").value;
var m = document.getElementById("pass").value;

 if (t === "username")
 {
    if(m === "password")
    {
        document.write("SUCCESS!")
    }

    else if (m != "tete")
    {
        document.write("wrong password");
    }
 }

 else {
    document.write("ERROR!")
 }
```

}

Comment: Not that it matters but S U C C E S S that's how you spell success

Comment: Put your input's inside a `<form>` and the clients browser will automatically observe the `enter` event

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus is correct. This doesn't work now?

Comment: As already said: The default method to submit an HTML form is to press the enter key. You don't even need a submit button to do so (except in Firefox). If an HTML form does not submit when hitting enter, you broke it with some code. Or you have invalid HTML, like inputs without a form surrounding them.

Comment: Document.write will wipe the page. Not a good idea. And use the form submit event and return false if you do not want to actually submit. Seeing it is a password form, you want to post it and not test the validity of a password in client side code

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus i've already tried that and it does work but only for like half a second but then it loads back to the forms mm can u please check again maybe i have a bug thats doing that btw am using chrome

Comment: @mplungjan thanks i know that but am just doing this for testing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that you need to add resp. change in your code, in order to work as expected:

- wrap your fields and the submit button into a [form](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)
- cancel the form submition event
- don't write directly to the document, but use an *output* panel, a div for example. This way you could even build a very simple log panel.

The code with the changes from above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test Form</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function check()
    {
        var t = document.getElementById("user").value;
        var m = document.getElementById("pass").value;
        // get the "output" panel
        var o = document.getElementById("output");

        if (t === "username")
        {
            if(m === "password")
            {
                // add text to the div as simple log
                o.innerHTML += "SUCCESS!<br />";
            }
            else if (m != "tete")
            {
                o.innerHTML += "wrong password<br />";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            o.innerHTML += "ERROR!<br />";
        }
        // bind to the submit event and cancel it, to prevent realod!
        document.getElementById('form1').onsubmit = function() {
            return false;
        }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- wrap your code in a form that gets submited on enter keypress -->
    <form id="form1" action="#" method="post">
        <h3>Start Here</h3>
        UserName: <input type="text" id="user"><br>
        Master Code: <input type = "password" id = "pass"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick= "check()">
        <div id="output"></div>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The data is submitted when the user presses either the enter key or the submit button.

Comment: Please use        
        `document.getElementById('form1').onsubmit = check;` and return false in check. It is not good practice to ie's the click event of a submit button

Comment: am sorry @mplungjan but what do you mean by ie's?

Comment: Auto complete. Not good practice to ***use*** the click event instead of the submit event